# How to redirect request to another page in drupal 6 based on a session variable

Tags: 6, hooks, redirection

I have installed Drupal 6 and working on custom module.

I want to redirect all user request to a confirmation page when he try to access any other URL.
The flaw is :

1. User login
2. If user status is set get confirm set a session variable and re-direct to another page
3. Confirm or cancel
4. When ever user try to access any other page show the confirmation page

I have an issue when user do not select any option and type the URL and go to another page. Then I want to check the session variable and redirect the user to confirmation page.

I tried with Drupal hook_init function implementation on my custom module but it gives a redirect loop.
CODE :

```
function customprints_init() {

    if ( $_SESSION['show_print_size_confirm'] && $_REQUEST['q'] != 'print/confirm/size' ) {
        drupal_goto("print/confirm/size");
    }
}
```

I can not do the check in template files as there are about 50 template files.

Is there a way to do this properly in a hook function or in a common place.

Comment: Why do you need to use this expensive `hook_init` hook at first place ? There are different methods to redirect upon login, form submission, etc. I'd suggest you to use one of them instead.

Comment: @AyeshK, I want to redirect user to an specific confirmation page whenever he access other pages without confirming. The condition is set based on user status.

Comment: longshot conjecture here, but give `$_GET['q'] != 'print/confirm/size'` instead of `$_REQUEST['q'] != 'print/confirm/size'` a shot as I've done almost exactly what you've done here without getting any redirect loops.  If that doesn't work, also check to make sure `print/confirm/size` is an actual drupal system path and not an alias, eg, `node/#` vs `pretty/path/to/content`.

Comment: @Jimajamma Thanks but still redirect loop. The path `'print/confirm/size'` is a path specified as an item in hook_menu implementation.